# Sync smartStore offline Data to Salesforce DB

Tags: ios, xcode, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi I was just trying an example with SFDC IOS native SDK.

Here how to upload the offline stored data to salesforce once connection is back. Is this we have to take care it manually or something smartStore will detect and it will synchronise automatically ?.

It it is manual how to do it with native IOS.

or is there any tutorial that clearly explains this concept ?

Also how to update and delete data in salesforce db ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are sample applications and tutorials available on salesforce site. You can find the Mobile SDK guide for download here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true

On page 189 there is mention to a sample native app the uses smartstore.

There is also the forceios utility that generates a template app for you and one of its options is to use smartstore. See page 20 for that.